# ASP.NET Core 2.x , Angular 4/5 with datatable

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, angular-datatables, uicomponents

I need to use datatable for showing the list of data with angular 4 bootstrap and asp.net core 2x version.I've tried some plugins like angular-2-data-table.But no hope,am getting lots of errors.I don't find any resource or idea in online for that.Could anyone please suggest me what to do for this ? Or any better options/suggestions for my development.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try [**prime-ng datatable**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable)

Comment: Ok Aravind , Thanks.. Let me try that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio or Dotnet CLI to create ASP.NET Core 2.X - the MVC Web App template uses latest Angular as UI framework and Bootstrap as CSS framework.

With Angular 2 - everything is a component. So the UI components you look for should be available as a component library. If you take a look at the official resources page of angular.io here - https://angular.io/resources - look for the section UI Components. It lists all open source/commercial component library available. Go through the list, understand their usage, look at the demos they have and decide which one suits your needs. Each component has documentation to get started. Do go through them thoroughly.

hope this helps.